# Given a random point and a cube, how can I determine the distance from that point to the furthest possible point on the cube?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d

Given a random point in space ( $\vec{p}$ ), I am trying to figure out how to calculate the distance to the furthest point on an axis-aligned cube/cuboid from that other point. This cube is defined by two corners which we will call $\vec{c_{l}}$ and $\vec{c_{h}}$. It is guaranteed that $\vec{c_l}$ is the corner on the cube with the lowest values for each of its axes and $\vec{c_h}$ is the corner on the cube with the highest values for each of its axes.

For what it's worth, I've figured out (I think) how to calculate the *closest* point on the cube to $\vec{p}$. The equation I've figured out for that is: $$min(max(\vec{p}, \vec{c_l}), \vec{c_h})$$ Despite figuring this out, I cannot figure out how to calculate the furthest point (or the distance to it, which is my ultimate goal).

To help illustrate what I am trying to do, here is a diagram I rendered. The red sphere is the closest point on the cube to $\vec{p}$.

[image: the image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the cube be defined by

$$x_1<x<x_3, \ \ \ \ y_1<y<y_3, \ \ \ \ z_1<z<z_3.$$

Let $M (x,y,z)$ be the coordinates of the given point.

The farthest point in the cube is necessarily a vertex.

- **First solution** : compute the 8 distances to the 8 vertices $(x_i,y_j,z_k)$ and choose the vertex realizing the maximum.
- **Second solution** (with much less computation) :

Let $$x_2=(x_1+x_3)/2, \ \ y_2=(y_1+y_3)/2, \ \ z_2=(z_1+z_3)/2$$

Algorithm : Just test the signs of ($(x-x_2),(y-y_2),(z-z_2)$).

Indeed, to each combination of signs $(-,-,-), (-,-,+), \cdots (+,+,+))$ is associated a precise vertex (an association that has to be computed beforehand, resulting in a simple "hash table").

Comment: Thank you so much!